# Creating an iOS Simulator Build for Facebook Review with RoboVM

Tags: ios, eclipse, robovm

How can we create an iOS simulator build using RoboVM and eclipse? It is required for Facebook Review which is done for approving write actions such as `publish_actions`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robovm/TO1xPZgUdPo) RoboVM group post does address your issue.

> You should be able to find the .app folder generated by the RoboVM
>   Eclipse plugin by looking in the "RoboVM console" in Eclipse. Launch
>   your app on the simulator from within Eclipse. Locate the ios-sim
>   command invocation in the console (probably at the end) and you should
>   see the absolute path to the .app folder as one of the arguments. This
>   is the folder you'd want to zip up and submit to Facebook.